# GitHub Actions fails to build a docker image for web app

Tags: docker, github-actions

Have a few queries around it

1. I have a docker build failing due to path. It works when I execute on local PC. What should be the path here?

```
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 14.15

      - name: Dependencies
        run: npm install --legacy-peer-deps

      - name: Build
        run: npm run build-prod

      - name: Docker Login
        run: docker login -u $USERNAME -p $PWD
          
      - name: Build
        run: docker build . --tag $REPO:latest
    
      - name: Docker Push
        run: docker push $REPO:latest
```

Error

```
> [3/3] COPY /dist/app-name /usr/share/nginx/html:
145
------
146
error: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to walk /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount67345738657/dist: lstat /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount67345738657/dist: no such file or directory
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM nginx:1.17.1-alpine
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY /dist/app-name /usr/share/nginx/html
```

2. How do I get the tag version when a new release is created to start the build with two tags: latest and {tag} created for the build. This is to keep build backups of old tags in docker. What will be the changes above to do two builds?

Comment: To answer your first question it would be good if you also give us the `Dockerfile`. But as far as I can see you try to copy stuff from `/dist`. I assume your files are somewhere under `GITHUB_WORKSPACE` (see https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/environment-variables for more details).

Comment: @MrPython Dockerfile attached. Running the above commands locally does create a dist folder locally .. just when this actions build is happening I believe it can't find it..

Comment: I have tried all these variations in the copy above ```./dist/app-name``` ```/home/runner/work/app-name/app-name/dist/app-name``` ... In local directory it creates a ```app-name/dist/app-name``` and works fine. Can't figure out what GitHub actions is doing. Looking at the build run it is creating the path ```/home/runner/work/app-name/app-name``` but I have tried it above by adding dist/app-name to it.. didn't work